# Как установить apk программно?

Tags: java, android

Пишу модуль для обновления приложения программно.

Необходимо установить новую версию .apk программно, чтоб клиент даже не знал что у него обновилось приложение.

Возможно ли это? И если да, то как?

Comment: Без рута вряд ли возможно.

Comment: нужно или рут-права или быть системным приложением с https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установить приложение программно в *silent mode* без прав рута в общем случае невозможно.

К тому же, если приложение с подобным функционалом опубликовано в Google Play, то оно может быть заблокировано (обновление должно быть опционально и только через Google Play).

Если есть рут, то можно примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926274/install-android-apk-without-prompt):

```
public static void installAPK(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command});
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Делается это так:

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path_to.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
//или если установка из маркета
installIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=app.package.name"));
startActivity(installIntent);
```

В любом случае, без одобрения юзера установка не пройдет: выскочит уведомление - типа *вы уверены?*

Answer (score 0):

Никак, надо просто запустить стандартную установку, а пользователь сам решит, надо ему это или нет.